# iPhone app rejected - because use of one private API function - but there is no alternative - what to do?

Tags: iphone, appstore-approval

I wrote a nice app that would simplify life for many - somehow similar to these phone card apps. However, there is one  private API function which I have to use to send a hash '#" in a phone call because the receiving hardware requires this. (which is understandably not allowed because of POSSIBLE abuse). But

> My app does not missuse or in any way
>   cause damage.

Certainly the reviewers at apple don't have time to review for each single use of such functions - so therefore my app got rejected by the automated API check (so I assume).  Yes I know that these issues are documented well by Apple, but I was hoping they would really "check" abuse possibilities of apps and then reject - or accept if the app is not harmfull in any way. (as happened in a similar case in appstore)

Anyway, if I don't find another solution this app will not be accepted.

What to do now? 
Does it make sense to write an explanation comment when submitting to review? 
Is there an alternative to send the signal of a # during a call somehow? 
Is there an alternative way to sell/distribute apps? Will this affect my future apps to be submitted? What is your experience?

ps certainly, the Android version is available soon...

Thanks!

Comment: They don't want to create a precedent; I don't think anyone at Apple has time to check all their private API functions to determine if they have unintended consequences or not. Maybe the function is private for a reason.

Comment: Certainly you are right - they just should find a save way to allow this functionality. I actually filed a bug report including a constructive suggestion how to savely provide this functionality in future releases

Comment: Apple generally doesn't like apps that use private APIs not because of the potential for malicious use so much as the fact that private functions can easily change between iOS versions and are not confirmed to be stable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option would be to submit it as a bug and request they "support send a hash '#" in a phone call".

Comment: In the meanwhile I filed the bug report and already got an answer back, saying this is a duplicate and is beeing dealt with. I am impressed by the speed and courtesy of the message I received from Apple. Now I hope that the bug will be dealt with in the same manner.

Comment: just checked in new iOS 4.3 - no improvements regarding this issue whatsoever!

Answer (score -1):

You can always try the [Cydia store](http://cydia.saurik.com/store/), and probably there are other ways in the jailbreak community.

Comment: ..I like that idea...any experience with that? how best to solve the issue that if a user finds a link to the store to EASILY download an app from there (esp if he/she doesn't have Cydia installed)?

Comment: Only Jailbroken iPhones can access Cydia and download the app, so it won't be available to the non-Jailbroken phones (which is a lot of them).

Comment: Knowing now that about 10% are jailbroken and that only 1% are checking apps in cydia, its not really an option I would like to pursue...

Comment: I just replied to your "Is there an alternative way to sell/distribute apps?" sub-question - I never said that Cydia would have the same user base with the Apple appstore. BTW, can you give us the source of your statistics? I'd like to have a look!